# .NET Machine learning libary that supports incremental training

Tags: .net, machine-learning

I'm looking for a .NET library that implements incremental machine learning algorithms (such as KNN or Naive Bayes).  I'm trying to integrate these algorithms into a system that will be receiving training data over time, so the incremental feature is a must.  I've looked at Accord.NET but none of its algorithms seem to support online learning.